# How to increase VM memory size for a JUnit test on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run a simple JUnit test that includes the following code:

```
    @Test
    public void testVeryLongString() {
            String s = "0123456789";
            String repeated = new String(new char[214748364]).replace("\0", s);
            assertEquals(2147483640, repeated .length());
   }
```

It fails on the above lines with "Requested array size exceeds VM limit".

I tried increasing the Run Configuration of this test to -Xmx18292m (on a 64GB Windows workstation) but I am still getting the dreaded "Requested array size exceeds VM limit".

What am I missing?

Is there a way to let the test proceed without failing on this VM limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Requested array size exceeds VM limit*** means that an array greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is attempted to be allocated. **Since Java 9 `String`** and `StringBuilder` (which is used for `String.replace(...)`) internally use each a **byte array twice the size of the string length** instead of a `char` array of the same length.

**With Java 8** and enough memory (much more than `-Xmx18292m` as additional arrays are required for doing `String.replace(...)`) to avoid an `OutOfMemoryError`, **it should work**.

For better performance and less memory requirements, use the following code:

```
@Test
public void testVeryLongString() {
    String s = "0123456789";
    char[] chars = new char[214_748_364 * s.length()]; // Java 9+: 107_374_182
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i += s.length()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            chars[i+j] = s.charAt(j);
        }
    }
    String repeated = new String(chars);
    assertEquals(2_147_483_640, repeated.length()); // Java 9+: 1_073_741_820
}
```

Comment: Your alternative code works beautifully. Thank you!